# Django admin, how to restrict a user to insert records only within his country?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I have this Model

```
  title= country = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
  city = models.ForeignKey(City)
  user = country = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Using the (Add Case +)page in the default Django admin, is there anyway to customise the country and city dropdown lists options depending on the current user? 
For example: if the current logged in user is from USA, then the country dropdown list will show only one option (USA), and the city dropdown list will show only the cities in USA.Then, this user would be allowed only to add cases related to his/her country.

Comment: Unrelated but this line `user = country = models.ForeignKey(User)` is redefining the `country` model field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: yes of course this is possible - **IF** you know which country your user belongs too of course.

You'll have to

1/ [exclude the `country` field from the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude),

2/ use [formfield_for_foreignkey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) to filter the `city` field's queryset

3/ and manually populate the model's field in your ModelAdmin's [`save_model()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

Note that just reading the modeladmin's doc could have answered your question - there are examples for very similar use cases.